# Comparing characters in Two Strings

Tags: python, string, comparison

I receive two string inputs from user: acela laced.

I use the string and split it to form a list.
`s = ['acela', 'laced']` and I call `s1=s[0]` and `s2=s[1]`.

Now I have to compare s1 and s2 such that:
If len(s1)==len(s2) and all individual characters of S2 are in S1 (sequential matching not relevant) then print 'Yes' else print No.

I have tried some coding for it, but I my outputs are either incorrect or they go yes yes yes yes no for every letter that is compared. I want just one output in the end per comparison - either yes or no for s1 and s2.

```
def compare(s1,s2):  
    if len(s1) == len(s2):
        for i in s2:
            if i in s1:
                print('yes')
            else:
                print('no')
```

(The code above is my idea, not an exact copy paste.) Basically, what I want is if the lengths and individual letters of the strings match, then print Yes else No. For ex: in my given example above, the answer should be No, as 'd' of laced doesn't exist in S1. (S1 is master list and S2 should be compared with S1.)

Example:
Inputs:

```
axle lxae
aaabab bacdba
ababa bbaaa
```

Outputs:

```
Yes
No
Yes
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: "I call s[0] = s1 and s[1] = s2" -- I think this is backwards.

Comment: Fixed that typo.

Comment: what about repeated characters? Do want to print `Yes` for `called` and `caledd`?

Comment: I have edited your query with an example. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My python skills are the strongest, but this should work. I will not say this is the best implementation, but it will work.

```
   def compare(s1,s2):  
    if len(s1) == len(s2):
        for i in s2:
            if i in s1:
                continue
            else:
                print('no')
                return;

        print('yes')
        return;
    print('no')
```

I removed an else, this is my personal preference.

```
def compare(s1,s2):  
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        print('no')
        return

    for i in s2:
        if i not in s1:
            print('no')
            return

    print('yes')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def compare(s1,s2):
    s1_list = list(s1)
    s2_list = list(s2)
    s1_list.sort()
    s2_list.sort()
    return 'yes' if s1_list == s2_list else 'no'
```

---

Testing with your sample strings...

```py
x = '''axle lxae
aaabab bacdba
ababa bbaaa'''

for line in x.split('\n'):
    print(compare(*line.split()))
# yes
# no
# yes
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s1,s2=map(str,input().split())
print(sorted(s1)==sorted(s2))
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using `set`s:

```
(len(s1)==len(s2)) & set(s2).issubset(s1)
# False
```

---

Evidence:

```
ex = '''axle lxae yes
aaabab bacdba no
ababa bbaaa yes
acela lacea yes
acace cceaa yes
accaa abcaa no
acela acel no'''

for s in ex.splitlines():
    s1, s2, expctd = s.split()
    res = (len(s1)==len(s2)) & set(s2).issubset(s1)
    print(expctd, res)
```

```
# yes True
# no False                                                    
# yes True                                                   
# yes True                                                   
# yes True                                                    
# no False  
# no False
```

Comment: Using sets raises repetitive characters to be not counted and the program goes incorrect.

Comment: Program passes every single example you posted here so far.

Comment: try passing: s1 = acela and s2 = acel. if s1 is declared a set, then len(s1) = 4 instead of 5 and program fails.

Comment: If you pass _s1 = acela and s2 = acel_, it should return False (or no) by your own requirements, because the length of the two strings shall be equal. In my code neither s1 or s2 is _declared_ as a set, so in my code you will find not a single len-function applied to a set. Did you simply try to _copy_ my approach for a first test instead of implementing it yourself wrong?

Comment: Added your acela/acel test to evidence section.

Comment: Ok, this logic works. It's been enough to give me a gist of how I should go about it and now I got it working the way I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Its function didn't change from my first edit when you accepted it until now. It's IMO simply exactly the translation of your two requirements 1. equal length 2. s2 consists of a subset of characters of s1. With a logical _and_ inbetween. But of course it's up to you what answer you define as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

the question modified. If you want to matching the character by index. 
You can use zip to compare the right position of character.

```
s = ['acela', 'laced']
s1 = s[0]
s2 = s[1]
def compare(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) == len(s2):
        for i, j in zip(s1, s2):
            if len(set([i,j])) != 1:
                return "no"
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"
res = compare(s1, s2)
print(res)
```

This can remove "abb" "aba" yes

Comment: if inputs are acela and lacea, then the output should be 'yes' but it is returning 'no. This is not working.

Comment: acela lacea should return yes
acace cceaa should return yes
accaa abcaa should return no
Basically the characters must match depsite of their repetitions.

Comment: At first, your question is not say, judge the answer beyond the index. So, I add the condition, if you want to matching the character by index, you can use my code. I don't know what is wrong with my condition.